# When I try to install Ubuntu /kubunu I get a blank screen

Tags: 13.04, hp

intento instalar ubuntu 13 desde una usb, pero luego de oprimir start para instalarlo, se apaga la pantalla y no sucede nada mas, lo mismo pasa con kubuntu, mi laptop es una hp compac CQ45 ¿que puedo hacer?...

English

I tried installing Ubuntu 13.04 from USB, but when I press start to install it, the screen goes blank, and nothing else happens, the same thing happens with Kubuntu, my laptop is a HP Compaq CQ45 what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying Ubuntu from the Live Disk without installing. The fix is to simply press the f3/Brightness key while or after Ubuntu loads. Apparently the screen brightness is switched to its lowest setting (ie OFF) early in the loading.